# how do you search for something in an array in java

Tags: java

I wan to create a public, non-static method that does this:

getContent : This method should take as input a String filename and return a String. The method should search for a file with name filename in the array drive and return the data that is stored in that TxtFile. If no such file exists in the array drive, the method should return null.

I don't know how to search for something in an array. can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: You can do it in several ways, I recommend looking at the File class and FileInputStreamClass, these should get you going.

Answer (score 3):

Come on, try it your self:

**Step1:** Read all the file Names from a directory.

**Step2:** Store the list of Files to a List.

**Step3:** Iterate the list, Write a conditions with a use the File.getName() method to compare and the name and your input.

```
if(file.getName().equals(inputFileName)){
   return "boooo! I have found You!"  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You search in an array by iterating of it. Something like this (if you are inside a method):

```
for(String x : someStringArray){
    if (somecondition(x))  return x;
}
```

Comment: but i also want it to return the data that is stored in TxtFile. Also, what do you mean by if (somecondition(x))?

Comment: If you are searching in an array you obviously need some condition that tells you if you found the correct element. That what you have to put in the place of 'somecondition'

Comment: so would it just be my arrayname(the thing I'm looking for)?

Comment: @slidepuppy1 - it *might* be.  The problem is that it is difficult to understand what you are really asking.

Comment: What I'm asking is how do I find this file in my array, and once I have found it, how do I get it to print out the data in that file

Answer (score 0):

this should be of help: [File search](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)

A definitive source for information.

EDIT: thought of something really simple:

```
String[] drives = new String[]{"C:\\", "D:\\"};
File file;

for(String drive : drives)
{
    file = new File(drive + "abc.txt");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, file.exists());
}
```

you can replace the showMessageDialogBox with whatever you want to do if the file exists.